# How to set the language of google autocomplete form to English?

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, google-places-api

I'm following [this](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-autocomplete-addressform) Google example of places autocomplete adressform.

The problem is that if I insert "Rome, Italy" the form returns in City "Roma" and in Country "Italia" (the language is Italian). I don't want the italian name, I want the English name. In the same example, if I insert "Roma, Italia" or "Rome, Italy" I want the form returns in City "Rome" and in Country "Italy".

What should I do for setting the language of the form only in English?

Here the javascript part:

```
var placeSearch, autocomplete;
var componentForm = {
  street_number: 'short_name',
  route: 'long_name',
  locality: 'long_name',
  administrative_area_level_1: 'short_name',
  country: 'long_name',
  postal_code: 'short_name'
};

function initAutocomplete() {
  // Create the autocomplete object, restricting the search to geographical
  // location types.
  autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(
      /** @type {!HTMLInputElement} */(document.getElementById('autocomplete')),
      {types: ['geocode']});

  // When the user selects an address from the dropdown, populate the address
  // fields in the form.
  autocomplete.addListener('place_changed', fillInAddress);
}

function fillInAddress() {
  // Get the place details from the autocomplete object.
  var place = autocomplete.getPlace();

  for (var component in componentForm) {
    document.getElementById(component).value = '';
    document.getElementById(component).disabled = false;
  }

  // Get each component of the address from the place details
  // and fill the corresponding field on the form.
  for (var i = 0; i < place.address_components.length; i++) {
    var addressType = place.address_components[i].types[0];
    if (componentForm[addressType]) {
      var val = place.address_components[i][componentForm[addressType]];
      document.getElementById(addressType).value = val;
    }
  }
}

// Bias the autocomplete object to the user's geographical location,
// as supplied by the browser's 'navigator.geolocation' object.
function geolocate() {
  if (navigator.geolocation) {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
      var geolocation = {
        lat: position.coords.latitude,
        lng: position.coords.longitude
      };
      var circle = new google.maps.Circle({
        center: geolocation,
        radius: position.coords.accuracy
      });
      autocomplete.setBounds(circle.getBounds());
    });
  }
}
```

And here the api with the key:

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=[API key]&libraries=places&callback=initAutocomplete" async defer></script>
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: It's not a good idea to publish your API key. I would remove it.

Comment: @JoachimRohde But when i will upload the website the key will be public, or not?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can change the language by adding `&language=[language here]` to the script tag. For English, that would be: `&language=en`

An example:

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&language=en"
type="text/javascript">
</script>
```

This is described [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/basics?csw=1#Localization) and there is a working example [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/map-language).